# Could not find a declaration file for module when import public component

Tags: typescript, vite

When I import the public component `"rd-component": "^0.1.53"` like this:

```
import { Pay } from "rd-component";
```

show error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'rd-component'. '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/rd-component@0.1.53_@types+node@16.18.28_react-redux@8.0.5_rollup@3.21.6_vite@4.3.5/node_modules/rd-component/dist/rd-component.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/rd-component` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'rd-component';`ts(7016)
```

I have added a `typings.d.ts` file in the project folder './typings/typings.d.ts', the file content look like:

```
declare module 'rd-component';
```

then add the type root config in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"typeRoots": [
     "./typings"
 ],
```

add include like this:

```
"include": [
    "src","typings/typings.d.ts"
  ]
```

when I run this config to build:

```
"build": "export NODE_ENV=production && tsc && vite build --mode production",
```

the dist folder did not contains the `typing.d.ts` define. Am I missing something? what should I do to make the vite compile the `typings.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command to print the module resolution detail info:

```
tsc ./src/[replace-with-your-own-filename].tsx --traceResolution
```

this command will help you to view the module resolution progress.